# React - Building a drag & drop hierarchical list with mouse and touch compatibility

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I need to build a drag-and-drop hierarchical list with mouse and touch compatibility in React. However, before trying to do it from scratch, I am looking for any libraries in React that can help me to do this.

From my research, I found this library for jQuery that is no longer being maintained. https://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/
is there something similar that exists for React? If not, how can I go about implementing this?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Comment: @sebtheiler yes. https://github.com/primetwig/react-nestable